# How to add another graph to AmCharts Gantt to show custom icons

Tags: amcharts, gantt-chart

I have a gantt chart with a few minor tweaks but basically a clone of [This gantt example with dates](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/gantt-chart-dates/).

What I am trying to do is have a number of icons next to the segment based off some info included in the segment data. My case involves having 3 different binary variables and including different icons depending the values.

```
  var chartData = [{
        category: task.name,
        segments: [
          {
            start: task.parallel ? lastStart : moment(latestEnd).format(string),
            end: task.parallel ? moment(lastStart).add(time,'m').format(string) : moment(latestEnd).add(time,'m').format(string),
            color: '#1C7DDB',
            time: task.time,
            indicator1: task.checkOne== 1 ? '../img/path_to_icon.svg' : '',
            indicator2: task.checkTwo== 1 ? '../img/path_to_icon2.svg' : '',
            indicator3: task.checkThree== 1 ? '../img/path_to_icon3.svg': ''
          }
        ]
      },
      ...
      }]
```

So far this works OK when I set the customeBullet to one of the variables:[image: gantt with custom bullet icon]

However I want to be able to have the ability to have all 3 (or none) of the icons shown.

I think what I need to do is add the segment data first then add the icons as three graphs to the gantt with no visible line.

My current chart init code is here, I tried changing `graph: {}` to `graphs: []` but that causes an error.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "plannerChart", {
      "type": "gantt",
      "marginRight": 70,
      "period": "DD",
      "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm",
      "columnWidth": 0.75,
      "addClassNames": true,
      "valueAxis": {
        "type": "date",
        "guides": [
          {
            "value": AmCharts.stringToDate( start, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN"),
            "toValue": AmCharts.stringToDate( moment(start).add(timeWindow,'h').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'), "YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN"),
            "lineAlpha": 0.2,
            "lineColor": guideColor,
            "lineThickness": 3,
            "fillAlpha": 0.1,
            "fillColor": guideColor,
            "label": "Available time",
            "inside": false
          }
        ]
      },
      "brightnessStep": 7,
      "graph": {
        "fillAlphas": 1,
        "lineAlpha": 1,
        "bulletOffset": 25,
        "bulletSize": 20,
        "customBulletField": "indicator1",
        "lineColor": "#0F238C",
        "fillAlphas": 0.85,
        "balloonText": "<b>Start</b>: [[start]]<br /><b>Finish</b>: [[end]]"
      },
      "rotate": true,
      "categoryField": "category",
      "segmentsField": "segments",
      "colorField": "color",
      "startDateField": "start",
      "endDateField": "end",
      "dataProvider": chartData,
      "chartCursor": {
        "cursorColor": "#0F238C",
        "valueBalloonsEnabled": false,
        "cursorAlpha": 0,
        "valueLineAlpha": 0.5,
        "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
        "valueLineEnabled": true,
        "zoomable": false,
        "valueZoomable": false
      },
    } );
  }
```

Any help appreciated!

M

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible in a Gantt chart as it only takes a single graph object, as you noticed when trying to use an array.

You can emulate a Gantt chart by making a [multi-segmented floating  bar chart](http://www.amcharts.com/kbase/multi-segmented-floating-bar-chart/), using the graph's `openField` property to simulate where the column starts. You can extend this to add your additional graph objects for your indicators and use a date-based valueAxis for your values (note that valueAxes require date objects or millisecond timestamps, so strings won't work) or use relative values like in the demo. Note that this is a little clunker than the Gantt chart in that you have to define multiple graph objects to simulate the segments on the same category.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I think the mechanics of that route will lead me to endless issues so I may just create  a bunch of different icons and do some logic to create combination icons instead. Keeps the chart code clean. I'll post here when I figure it out. If it's too painful I might just try and go this route.